# Angular Karma testing - ReferenceError: Stripe is not defined

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

When i'm trying to test using karma, it showing

```
ReferenceError: Stripe is not defined
```

Component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { ApiService } from "../services/api.service";
import { EnvironmentService } from "src/environments/environment.service";
import { AlertService } from "ngx-alerts";
import { NgxSpinnerService } from "ngx-spinner";
import {
  NgbModal,
  ModalDismissReasons,
  NgbModalOptions,
} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

declare var Stripe: any;
@Component({
  selector: "app-cardinfo",
  templateUrl: "./cardinfo.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./cardinfo.component.scss"],
})
export class CardinfoComponent implements OnInit {
  card: any;

  deliveryDetails: any;
  billingAddress: any;
  name: any;
  creditCardName: any;
  cartId: any;
  cartDetails: any;
  clientSecret: any;
  stripePublicKey: any;
  stripe: any;
  creditCard: any;

  title = "ng-bootstrap-modal-demo";
  closeResult: string;
  modalOptions: NgbModalOptions;

  constructor(
    public router: Router,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    public apiService: ApiService,
    private envService: EnvironmentService,
    private alertService: AlertService,
    private spinner: NgxSpinnerService,
    private modalService: NgbModal
  ) {
    this.spinner.show();
    this.creditCard = true;

    this.stripePublicKey = this.envService.read("stripePublicKey");
    this.cartId = localStorage.getItem("cartId");
    this.deliveryDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("deliveryDetails"));
    this.billingAddress = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("billingAddress"));
    if (!this.cartId) {
      this.spinner.hide();
      localStorage.setItem("val", "0");
      this.router.navigate(["product"]);
    }
    this.apiService.getCartDetais(this.cartId).subscribe((res) => {
      this.cartDetails = res.body.cart;
      this.clientSecret = this.cartDetails.client_secret;
      this.name =
        this.cartDetails.recipientName + " " + this.cartDetails.lastName;
      this.spinner.hide();
    });

    this.modalOptions = {
      backdrop: "static",
      backdropClass: "customBackdrop",
    };
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    var stripe = Stripe(this.stripePublicKey);
    this.stripe = stripe;
    var elements = stripe.elements();
    var card = elements.create("card", { style: style });
    card.mount("#card-element");
    this.card = card;
  }

  confirm() {
    if (!this.creditCardName) {
      this.alertService.danger("Name is required!");
      return;
    }
    this.spinner.show();
    this.stripe
      .confirmCardSetup(this.clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: this.card,
          metadata: {
            cartId: this.cartId,
            addedFrom: "elderly-customer",
          },
          billing_details: {
            name: this.creditCardName,
          },
        },
        //  setup_future_usage: 'off_session'
      })
      .then((result) => {
        this.spinner.hide();
        console.log("result", result);
        if (result.error) {
          this.alertService.danger(result.error.message);
        } else {
          if (result.setupIntent.status === "succeeded") {
            this.alertService.success("Order placed successfully");
            this.router.navigate(["confirmation"]);
          }
        }
      });
  }

  goBack() {
    this.router.navigate(["deliverydate"]);
  }
}
```

Spec.ts

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";

import { CardinfoComponent } from "./cardinfo.component";
import { RouterTestingModule } from "@angular/router/testing";
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpClientModule,
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";
import { NgxStripeModule } from "ngx-stripe";
import { AlertService } from "ngx-alerts";
import { TestAlertService } from "../services/test-alert.service";

describe("CardinfoComponent", () => {
  let component: CardinfoComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CardinfoComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [CardinfoComponent],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientModule, NgxStripeModule],
      providers: [
        HttpClient,
        FormBuilder,
        HttpHandler,
        {
          provide: AlertService,
          useClass: TestAlertService,
        },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CardinfoComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it("should create", () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

After Edit

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";

import { CardinfoComponent } from "./cardinfo.component";
import { RouterTestingModule } from "@angular/router/testing";
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpClientModule,
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";
import { NgxStripeModule } from "ngx-stripe";
import { AlertService } from "ngx-alerts";
import { TestAlertService } from "../services/test-alert.service";

describe("CardinfoComponent", () => {
  let component: CardinfoComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CardinfoComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [CardinfoComponent],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientModule, NgxStripeModule],
      providers: [
        HttpClient,
        FormBuilder,
        HttpHandler,
        {
          provide: AlertService,
          useClass: TestAlertService,
        },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CardinfoComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    window.Stripe = function () {
      // your mock here
    };
  });

  it("should create", () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to mock your `Stripe` object in window object I guess like:

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
  window.Stripe = function () {
    // your mock here
    return {
      elements: () => ({
        create: () => ({
          mount: () => ({ /* your card */ })
        })
      })
    }
  }

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ CardinfoComponent ],
    imports: [RouterTestingModule,HttpClientModule,NgxStripeModule],
    providers: [
      HttpClient,
      FormBuilder,
      HttpHandler,
      { 
        provide: AlertService, 
        useClass: TestAlertService 
      }
    ]
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));
```

Regarding typing support, you might have to declare this Stripe object in you window object. Assuming that you have a file which declares `typings/overrides.d.ts`, then you add following code:

```js
declare interface Window {
  Stripe: any; // Or you can define a type for that in this file as well
}
```

Comment: when i'm adding this code, it showing "Property 'Stripe' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'."

Comment: I edited the answer to help you resolve typing issue

Comment: I just created a file 'overrides.d.ts' and added above code in that file...
and added _beforeEach_ code in my spec.ts, still the issue, showing...

Comment: You shouldn't have split it as new block. I meant you just added your mock at the beginning of the first beforeEach. I edited the answer snippet again. You can double check again.

Comment: yeah... issue solved.... thankyou so much brother....

Comment: one more issue is heading up now...
'TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined'

Comment: You have to implement your mock yourself. But as my understanding you would have to return an object includes `{ elements: () => yourResult }`

Comment: I also edited the snippet based on my knowledge on your case. Hopefully it would help

Answer (score 2):

For anyone trying to get their tests working with Stripe, If the above doesn't work out, you can include Stripe right on the window by adding the following in the beforeEach block which worked for me.

```
(window as any).Stripe = function () {
  // your mock here
  return {
    elements: () => ({
      create: () => ({
        mount: () => ({}),
        addEventListener: () => ({}),
        update: () => ({})
      })
    })
  }
}
```